# Error when trying to benchmark the substrate-node-template -- "Found argument 'Cargo.toml' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context"

Tags: substrate-node-template, benchmarking, benchmark

I'm trying to benchmark the pallet_template from the substrate-node-template example but am getting the error: `Found argument 'Cargo.toml' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context`.

I have already built the runtime with the `runtime-benchmarks` flag enabled, and have also included the `list_benchmark!(list, extra, pallet_template, TemplateModule)` and `add_benchmark!(params, batches, pallet_template, TemplateModule)` in the `runtime/lib.rs`. But when I run the command -

```
./target/release/node-template benchmark pallet \
    --chain dev \
    --execution=wasm \
    --wasm-execution=compiled \
    --pallet pallet_template \
    --extrinsic * \
    --steps 50 \
    --repeat 20 \
    --output pallets/template/src/weight.rs
```

I keep getting this weird error: `Found argument 'Cargo.toml' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context`. I have used the exact same command mentioned on the official substrate benchmarking tutorial and don't understand why the compiler is telling me that I'm passing `Cargo.toml` as an argument. I'm still a beginner in Substrate so please forgive me if I'm asking a very dumb question .

Please help me understand where I'm missing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your shell you have to escape the `*` symbol or put it into quotes.
Please try again with `--extrinsic ""`, `--extrinsic "\*"` or `--extrinsic "*"` which should all be equialent.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked after putting `*` in quotes.

Comment: Please consider marking your question as "answered" so that other people can easily find it.